# Custom deallocation function for tokens destructor in Lemon

Tags: c, parsing, lemon

I want Lemon to parse a simple C-like expression, supporting integer and string comparison over a predefined set of variables with known names. Let's assume it supports *only* string comparison, for simplicity. So, the following string is a good example of the expression kind I'm talking about:

```
a == "literal_1" || a == "literal_2"
```

So, my lexer would have to feed the parser with values it the following order:

```
void *p = parserAlloc(malloc);
parser(p, TOK_VARIABLE_A, NULL);
parser(p, TOK_OPERATOR_EQ, NULL);
parser(p, TOK_LITERAL, strdup("literal_1"));
parser(p, TOK_OPERATOR_OR, NULL);
parser(p, TOK_VARIABLE_A, NULL);
parser(p, TOK_OPERATOR_EQ, NULL);
parser(p, TOK_LITERAL, strdup("literal_2"));
parserFree(p, free);
```

I have to make duplicates of literal strings passed to parser, because they may contain escape sequences which I must decode first. But who is responsible to free the memory after the parsing is done? Fortunately, Lemon comes to the rescue with its `%destructor` directive, so I can write:

```
%token_destructor TOK_LITERAL { free($$); }
```

But in fact, I don't want to hard-code the usage of `malloc`, `strdup` and `free` in my parser and lexer. I want being able to pass allocator and deallocator functions as parameters, but use them not only in `parserInit` and `parserFree`, but also for token allocation and deallocation.

How can I declare additional parameter for `parserAlloc` to pass both `malloc` and `free` at the same time? There is the `%extra_argument` directive in Lemon, but it makes me pass my parameter every time I feed a token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `malloc` argument to `parserAlloc` is not stored anywhere, because the lemon-generated parser never allocates memory. [Note 1] And, of course, the `free` function is not stored anywhere either, because it isn't provided until you call `parserFree`.

Normally, you won't need an alloc function inside a parser action either, but if you use `%destructor`/`%token-destructor`, then you will want a `free` function. The only documented mechanism to do that is the extra-argument feature, which, as you say, requires supplying the argument on every call to the parser. That's a bit annoying, particularly since the parser immediately stores it into the parser state structure (i.e. the first argument to `parse`), but that's the way it is. It would be easy to change, and Lemon is unencumbered so you can make the changes you want to. But as provided, `%extra-argument` is the only way.

If you needed both alloc and free functions in your actions, for whatever reason, you could make the `%extra-argument` be a pointer to a struct (which is actually the normal case for `%extra-argument`); the struct would contain pointers to both functions. Alternatively, you could use a function with the standard `realloc` interface: `realloc(NULL, sz)` is equivalent to `malloc(sz)` and `realloc(p, 0)` is equivalent to `free(p)` (as long as `p` is not NULL). See `man realloc` for details. That won't bother the lemon parser, because it never uses either malloc or free.

#### Notes

1. That's not quite true. There is an as-far-as-I-know undocumented feature: if you set `%stack-size 0`, then the generated parser will reallocate the parser stack before it overflows instead of throwing an error. In that case, the parser uses the standard library `realloc` to allocate or reallocate the stack, not the malloc function provided to `parserAlloc`, and `parserFree` frees the stack with the standard library `free`, not the function passed as an argument.

Comment: Just checked the `%stack_size 0` issue. Indeed, it generated calls to `realloc` which seems to be way so odd to me. It's so inconsistent with `parserAlloc` and `parserFree`.